# Check Each Values of Two Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I want to check 2 values of array below and replace value on **Array B** with 0 or 1 values if that each array values is match or not with **Array A**.
Here is my array data:

**Array A**:

[image]

```
Array (
    [a1] => 2
    [a2] => 2
    [a3] => 3 )
```

**Array B**:

[image]

```
Array (
[0] => Array
    (
        [a1] => 2
        [a2] => 1
        [a3] => 3
        [so] => 7
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [a1] => 3
        [a2] => 2
        [a3] => 2
        [so] => 8
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [a1] => 1
        [a2] => 3
        [a3] => 4
        [so] => 9
    ) )
```

And this is the output what i expect:

[image]

Any idea how to do this in PHP? Because i'm still confused how to combine array_diff or array_intersect with foreach loop

Comment: I absolutely do not understand what you want to say with your first sentence. Could you please rephrase that? Apart from that: Better post code of your arrays, potential helpers can then copy&paste it and don't have to create their own, and also: Yes, there is most possibly someone who has an idea how to do it, but, SO is not a coding service. Please also include your own approaches so far in your question, and why you failed with them.

Comment: Look up how Multideminsional arrays work.  That's what you're looking for.  Essentially, each variable is going to be in a matrix to be referenced like "a1[x][y]"

Comment: ArSeN: I has updated my reason, and i'm not begging anyone to code. I'm just confused and curious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not the most elegant solution, but it works:

```
$a = array
    (
        'a1' => 2,
        'a2' => 2,
        'a3' => 3
    );

$b = array ( 
    array
    (
        'a1' => 2,
        'a2' => 1,
        'a3' => 3,
        's0' => 7
    ),

    array
    (
        'a1' => 3,
        'a2' => 2,
        'a3' => 2,
        's0' => 8
    ),

    array
    (
        'a1' => 1,
        'a2' => 3,
        'a3' => 4,
        's0' => 9
    ) );


$c = array ();

$i=0;
foreach ($b as $b_row)
{
    $c[$i]['a1'] = ( $a['a1'] == $b_row['a1'] ) ? 1 : 0;
    $c[$i]['a2'] = ( $a['a2'] == $b_row['a2'] ) ? 1 : 0;
    $c[$i]['a3'] = ( $a['a3'] == $b_row['a3'] ) ? 1 : 0;
    $c[$i]['s0'] = $b_row['s0'];
    $i++;
}
```

or a bit more compact:

```
$i=0;
foreach ($b as $b_row)
{
    foreach ($b_row as $b_cell => $value)
    {
        if (isset ($a[$b_cell])) 
        {
            $c[$i][$b_cell] = ( $a[$b_cell] == $value ) ? 1 : 0;
        }
        else 
        {
            $c[$i][$b_cell] = $value;
        }
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: So, instead using if else to determine 1 or 0, it'll be better using "?" to determine it..

Comment: Yeah that works just as well. I used if else, because I find nested ? : harder to read,

Answer (score 0):

Can't test just now but it maybe something like this

```
foreach ($arrayB as &$ar)
   foreach ($ar as $k => &$v)
      if (isset($arrayA[$k]) 
          $v = ($v == $arrayA[$k] ? 1 :0);
```

Comment: It almost works, but "so" column is gone. Is there any other way how to keep "so" column?

Comment: so column is not changed becouse it does not present in arrayA